# Able to make multiple comments - how to send unique ID with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this script that loads another php page, that contains some captcha and the actually comment form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Stops the page from jumping to top when using a href
    $('#button_comment').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
    // Loads dashboard/comment(.php) into the div comment_form_and_captcha
    $("#button_comment").click(function(){
    $("#comment_form_and_captcha").load("<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>dashboard/comment");
});
</script>
```

And that script is fired with this href link:

```
    <!-- The href that fires the script to load the comment.php into div -->
   <a id="button_comment" href="#" role="button">comment</a><br>
        <!-- dashboard/comment(.php) is loaded into div1 -->
   <div id="comment_form_and_captcha"></div>
```

But with multiple "posts" on same page that users can comment on, the current configuration doesn't work.

**My thoughts how to do this**

I could probably load the `$("#comment_form_and_captcha").load("<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>dashboard/comment");` with additional information, like the post ID `"dashboard/comment/"+ id`. And additional `id` from the firing href `<a id="button_comment_id_234" href="#" role="button">comment</a>` (id_234 pseudo). So that `dashboard/comment` knows with post that is being commented on.

**My question/s**

- How do i send the ID to the script? (And receive it)
- And because of the captcha is    written to session, and a new
  captcha is generated when clicking the    link, how to "close" or
  "unload" an already open/loaded div    `comment_form_and_captcha`?
- Is this the way to go? Or is there another, better way?

Comment: You can use javascript function on onclick event to send the ID . Read this tutorial to take an idea how to send id dynmically on onlcik function with javascript and make ajax call http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-edit-delete-and-update-data-without-refreshing-page-in-codeigniter/